# TimeoutException during test that extends GWTTestCase class

Tags: gwt, gwttestcase

I have test class that extends GWTTestCase.class.

When I am trying to debug my test - I can't even go through first line at my test class, because my class extends GWTTestCase and during test time some proccess inside it throws next exception:

```
[ERROR] 503 - GET /com.energyict.ems.portal.Portal.JUnit/junit.html (127.0.0.1) 336 bytes

com.google.gwt.junit.client.TimeoutException: The browser did not contact the server within 60000ms.
 - 1 client(s) haven't responded back to JUnitShell since the start of the test.
 Actual time elapsed: 60.236 seconds.
Try increasing this timeout using the '-testBeginTimeout minutes' option
The default value of minutes is 1, i.e., the server waits 1 minute or 60 seconds.


        at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.notDone(JUnitShell.java:1039)
        at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1363)
        at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1283)
        at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTest(JUnitShell.java:672)
        at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runTest(GWTTestCase.java:421)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
        at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
        at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.run(GWTTestCase.java:247)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; support was removed in 8.0

    Process finished with exit code -1
```

Can anyone please give a suggetsion about it ?

I am using `<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>` version 2.20

Comment: Can you share the test? Especially are you doing any calls to delay test finish and make the test async? Have you tried increasing the timeout? And were there any earlier log messages?

Comment: I have the same problem.  It happens for a trivial test with nothing but assertEquals(true).  There is a long delay and then the message:  [ERROR] 503 - GET /whatever.my.package.is.JUnit/junit.html (127.0.0.1) 336 bytes